# Create a Planning table itext

Tags: java, spring, itext, itext7

I'm trying to create a planning table using iText 7 and my database.

The table must be like this:
[image]

I have a list of objects, and these objects contain all data that I want put inside this table.

But I don't understand how can I put the correct work under the correct column. 
For example how can I put "Do this" under "Tec 1" and "Do that" under "Tec 3" for 23/05/2017?

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea behind filling an iText Table object is that you define how many columns you're going to have, and then you add cells to the table. As soon as you've completed a row, iText will automatically move to the next row.

So, for your example.

- construct a new Table object with (n+1) columns
- write the header cells, and format them to have gray background
- write complete rows

You can of course build your own intermediary class that allows you to set content at a specific row/column combination (or in your case header/date). 
This intermediary class can then have a method that converts its entire content to an iText Table object.